# Unexpected promise instead of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm working with node and mongo. I'm trying to run a series of parallel requests using a netlify serverless function which I'm trying to create build using mongo records. So far I have:

```
paralellNum = 2;

const filter = { 'Parcel': { $regex: '[0-9]' }, 'UseCode': { $exists: false } };
let records = await collection.find(filter).limit(firstNum).toArray()
console.log('number of records selected from db: ', records.length);

const fetchURL = (obj) => fetch('http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/meta1', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});

  let outputArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < (paralellNum-1); i++) {
    const record  = records.pop();
    const obj = {"_id":record._id,"apn":record.Parcel};
    outputArray.push(fetchURL(obj));
  } 

  console.log(outputArray);
```

I was expecting the output array to contain the constructed fetch requests, but instead I'm seeing:

```
1) [Promise]
0:
Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined, 
Symbol(async_id_symbol): 59, Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 58}
length:1
```

Whay am I getting a promise instead of the expected array?

Comment: `fetch` is an async function, so it returns a `Promise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for all the Promises to finish with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
Promise.all(outputArray).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    // use result here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a promise for the request.  If you want the response of the requests to be in your `outputArray` you need to change `outputArray.push(fetchURL(obj));` to `fetchUrl(obj).then(response => outputArray.push(response));`

This waits for the fetch call to finish and then takes the response and puts it into your array.